# Простой X-Window под линукс

Tags: linux

Программе под линукс требуется X-Window. Подскажите, что можно поставить для удовлетворения этого требования. По идее достаточно, чтобы программа видела дисплей.

Comment: Не очень понял вопрос. 

Если надо транслировать программы, то наверное надо начать с 

     sudo apt-get install libx11-dev

а дальше смотреть, что конкретно надо доставить.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился установкой vnc4server.